# getting hour from pandas datetime compatible with summer time changes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have an algorithm that takes as input the time in seconds (epoch) and a value.  It must compare the value of today with the values of the previous days at the same time.

For example :   compare today at 5:04 a and yesterday at 5:04 and so on.

The change to summer time should not break this logic.  To achieve the desired result I convert the epoch in a `datetime.datetime` object and then I count the number of seconds since midnight. 
`dt-dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)`

This seems to work well using the python `datetime.datetime` class.  Unfortunately it breaks when converting to a pandas datetime.  Pandas seems to be handling the change of hour by changing the timezone.

This example shows the difference between pandas datetime and datetime.datetime:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pytz

timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome')


dt_rome = timezone.localize(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 13, 0, 0))
dts_rome = [dt_rome - datetime.timedelta(hours=24),
            dt_rome,
            dt_rome + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)]

pd_dts_rome = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dts_rome))

print 'hour according to python datetime', [dt.hour for dt in dts_rome]
print 'hour according to pandas datetime', [dt.hour for dt in pd_dts_rome]


print 'secs in period python datetime:', [dt-dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
                                          for dt in dts_rome ]
print 'secs in period pandas datetime:'
print pd_dts_rome.apply(lambda dt: dt-dt.replace(hour=0, minute=0,
                                                 second=0, microsecond=0)).astype(int)/1.e9
```

output:

```
hour according to python datetime [13, 13, 13]
hour according to pandas datetime [14, 13, 13]

secs in period python datetime: [datetime.timedelta(0, 46800), datetime.timedelta(0, 46800), datetime.timedelta(0, 46800)]

secs in period pandas datetime:
0    50400.0
1    50400.0
2    46800.0
dtype: float64
```

given that the data is stored in a pandas dataframe. How can I get the same results that I get with datetime.datetime with pandas.datetime?

Comment: You're writing new Python 2 code in 2019?  It's six months away from EOL: https://www.anaconda.com/end-of-life-eol-for-python-2-7-is-coming-are-you-ready/

Comment: yes unfortunately it is not my decision :-(

Answer (score 0):

The times you're seeing are really equivalent, but in a weird way.  The Pandas times are:

```
0   2018-10-27 14:00:00+02:00
1   2018-10-28 13:00:00+01:00
2   2018-10-29 13:00:00+01:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Rome]
```

2018-10-28 03:00:00 was when DST ended in Rome.  Pandas Series only has a single logical timezone which applies to all the values--this is done to save space and improve performance.  So your timezone is Europe/Rome.  Of course, 14:00:00+02:00 is the same physical time as 13:00:00+01:00.

The Python times are:

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 27, 13, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Rome' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 13, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Rome' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 29, 13, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Rome' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

The first one differs because Python is using the wrong time offset, i.e. not really Europe/Rome, because Rome wasn't on CET at that time.  This is rather strange, and arguably less correct than what Pandas produced, so it's a bit awkward to ask "How do I make Pandas do the same [wrong] thing that Python does?"

But if you need to, you can:

```
timezone = pytz.FixedOffset(1)
```

The rest of the code remains the same.  What this does is say "My time zone offset is +1 hour, always."  Then Pandas will not notice when DST turns on and off:

```
0   2018-10-27 13:00:00+00:01
1   2018-10-28 13:00:00+00:01
2   2018-10-29 13:00:00+00:01
dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(1)]
```

Python 3 users can use the built in `datetime.timezone(1)` instead, but since you're on Python 2, `pytz.FixedOffset(1)` does the job.

Comment: Given that I have to compare actions at the same time in the day with seconds resolution.  I guess this is the correct way to proceed?  Does it generalize to different timezones ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see.

Comment: I think I can not use this solution as I get as input a timezone and not an offset. I do not think this will generalize.